# Back up and shut down

Tags: backup, shutdown

At the end of the day, I would like my MacBook Pro to back-up to both Time Machine and Backblaze (or verify that it has done so) and then shut down. Could someone write please write a script that would implement this? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried by yourself to accomplish these tasks? If you have tried but failed, where did it go wrong? One cannot simply ask to have somebody write a script for you in this forum. Most of us are willing to help provided you have first attempted a solution yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Backblaze, but one option would be to edit the crontab with `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` and add a line like this:

`0 18 * * * tmutil startbackup -b && osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to shut down'`